# Parsing plain text list into multiple text files

Tags: parsing

I have a collection of daily MP3s that I'm expected to upload to a web server once a month — they're named with a consistent format (ex. `10-17-11 Always Expect the Best # 1.mp3`) and for each file, I have to generate an .m3u file with the URL to the web-server link. At the moment, I manually create each .m3u file and save it in relation to the MP3.

There must be a way to generate the .m3u files automatically — they usually are in the format of `http://url/audio/2011/10-17-11_.mp3`. I've created a plain text list of each filename on a separate line — if possible, I'd like to take that list and parse it into individual .m3u files.

I'm not sure what I should be using to do this — Python, Ruby, maybe just AppleScript?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you probably could do it with any of those, i'll give you a few pointers with python:

```
 with open("my_file","r") as fin:             ## open a file for reading
   i = 0
   for line in fin:                           ## iterate through all lines
     newline = line + line.split(" ")[0]      ## create a new line
     with open("output"+str(i),"w") as fout:  ## open a file for writing
       fout.write(newline)                    ## write...
     i+=1
```

This script reads a file and for each line appends the first word and writes it to its own file.
You can modify the loop code to aggregate several lines each time and write them to a file. And you can extract information from the line you read and use it to construct the new line.